# Create random string and check its uniqueness in DB

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Check the code bellow, the `RandomMan.MyRandomString(64)` is generating a random string of 64 char.

Now I want to check if this random string is unique in database using entityframework query like bellow. And if this string is not unique in database then it will continue the `do` loop until it finds a unique random string. Now my question is am I doing it correctly? Or is there any better way than that?

```
string randstr;
do {
    randstr = RandomMan.MyRandomString(64);
} while (DataCtx.StorageFiles.Any(x => x.AwsUniqueFileName == randstr));
```

Comment: Why not just use an auto-incrementing identity field in the database? Is there any reason you need to use a random string? Anyway, I hope that you also have a unique index on the AwsUniqueFileName field to prevent the (incredibly unlikely, given the string length) chance that two clients simultaneously decide that the same filename is unique and both insert the same value.

Comment: Yes. Because it is file name and its storing file under that name. Its need to be unique because i have to call that file later on that name

Comment: It only has to be unique, not random, right? (Analogous to this example: this is a sequence of unique numbers: `1,2,3,4,5`, where the numbers are not random but follow some very specific order)

Comment: "auto-incrementing" means increasing, as per @elgonzo's sequence. That is sufficient for a random filename. If you want a fixed width then you can format that in code to have leading zeroes, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot tell whether or not you are doing it correctly, but if you already have the row in DB, I could suggest concatenating (adding) your identity field `id` to the produced string so you make sure that the result is unique in the DB, given that your `MyRandomString` only produces chars (or no numbers at the end)

Let's say your generated string is `abc` and the `id` of the row you are updating is `53` then your final unique string is going to be `abc53`

Comment: This is killer idea. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Standard approach for this is to just generate [GUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier):

```
Console.WriteLine(Guid.NewGuid());
```

It's designed to be unique and highly unlikely to generate two identical GUIDs even on many instances at the same time so you don't need to worry much about atomicity of this operation.

The possibility of collision is so low that you can skip handling it at all, but just to be sure you can set unique key on this column and treat it as an exception, no need for loop for sure.